# react-query refetch api call with cache issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, react-query

I built a form using react,react-query,

[link to the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-zcf11t?file=/src/App.tsx)

**I built custom fields:**

- CacheAutocompleteField - cache field using react-query

  - queryAsyncFunc props - get async function and cache the data using react-query

**I have 3 fields:**

- Type - Select field
- Country - CacheAutocompleteField
- City - CacheAutocompleteField

**My scenario:**

I select any type from my hardcoded list (Type A, Type B , Type C),

I search any country, then I search any city

**What I'm trying to do?**

- every time I select a new type (from type options) - I want the country and city fields to be reset.
- every time I already search the same key (the queryKey is combined of cacheKey+inputValue) , it will not call to api, it will get the results from cache (that's what I chose to use from react-query to do).

**What I'm getting when I run my code?**

- When I select a type A, enter a country “Island” it will fetch data from api and get the data.
  Then when I select a type B, enter a country “Island” - It will fetch data from api and get the data.
  But when I select a type A and and same country “Island” again - I don’t want it to fetch data from api - I want it to get data from cache (that’s the reason I chose to work with react-query too) because it already search for this data with the same type. The queryKey is depended of other type field.
- when I search anything from autocomplete and it not find it, then I try to reset it by select any other type, it will kind of reset the value of the input but it still exist in inputValue of the country.
  for example I select type C, then enter "lakd" in country, then select any other type, it not reset it. reset works for me only when anything find in autocomplete and I select it. I guess it's because the autocomplete component not have inputValue props, but when I use it it make me other issues.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needn't call `refetch`. It call the API regardless of the cache.
Comment/Remove this code

```
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (debounceInputValue.length > 1) {
  //     refetch();
  //   }
  // }, [debounceInputValue, refetch]);
```

And you should enable the `useQuery`

```
enabled: true,
```

And use `debounceInputValue` instead of `inputValue` for `useQueryData`

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-d84rf4?file=/src/components/FormFields/CacheAutocompleteField.tsx:1255-1263